# PHP not receiving any data from XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, php, xmlhttprequest

I cannot seem to send any POST data to a PHP file via XMLHttpRequest. I have read many questions like this one but everyone had a different issue - none of them seem to be the case here.

I have boiled these two files down to their *absolute core basics* and it is still is not receiving any POST data. I have done this the exact same way in plenty of other instances before and I'm not sure how this one is any different.

index.php

```
...
<button id="login-button">Log in</button>
...
```

Javascript:

```
function login() {
  let ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
  ajax.open('POST', 'login.php', true);
  ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
  ajax.onload = function() {
      alert(this.response);
  };
  ajax.send({user:'hello', password:'there'});
}
document.getElementById('login-button').addEventListener('click', login)
```

login.php:

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

The alert message with the output, every single time, simply reads:

```
array(0) {
}
```

The JS and PHP are both in the same folder of the same website on the same server, running PHP 7 if that matters. What could I possibly be doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you opened the browser's developer tools and had a look at the network tab?

Comment: Try to change the send function to ajax.send("user=hello&password=there") and see what you get

Comment: `ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');` tells the server to expect url-encoded data, but then you've sent something else (which I assume is maybe an attempt to send JSON data, but isn't valid as such).

Comment: How are you capturing the button click event?

Comment: @JayBlanchard Please see the above Javascript.

Comment: @Aaron That does work!  Why isn't it working with the object notation in this case?  That's what I use everywhere else.

Comment: @HenryFloyd because it expects your data be url-encoded format and NOT an object of whatever kind. Do some googling and you will find a way to send JSON data as well :)

Comment: However I will add an answer just in case somebody is looking for a ready to use answer

Comment: Added an answer, give it a try :) @HenryFloyd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');` you basically tell your request to expect url-encoded data.

Lets keep it very simple, you want to submit a username and password.

So the request should look like this `ajax.send("username=hello&password=there")`

In your sample code you tried to send I dont know what kind of object-notation. The go-to way to exchange data between frontend and backend is JSON.

To modify your example to work with json modify it in the following way:

```
ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
let data = JSON.stringify({"username": "hello", "password": "there"});
ajax.send(data);
```

To get an object out of a valid JSON string you can use the json parse method
pe this helps you out :)

Comment: Note that the PHP side has to be changed too, in order to read incoming JSON data - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18866571/receive-json-post-with-php